# ACS and SAML 2.0

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0, acs

We have been for a while integrated with ACS in order to allow our customers to use their provider to use their login/password. We successfully use it for our ASP.NET application. In this case our application asks ACS for login (WsFederation), ACS redirects prompt to customer ADFS login page and user gets authenticated.

Now we have a new customer. The customer does not use ADFS from their site, but they use SAML 2.0 provider.

What would be the easiest way to get integrated with customer’s SAML 2.0 provider?

Answer (score 0):

So you have ADFS and the customer doesn't?

They have a SAML IDP?

If so, simply federate your ADFS and their SAML provider.

BTW, ACS is supposedly deprecated and will disappear one day so be prepared.

You could use Azure AD which supports both WS-Fed and SAML.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have ADFS for any current customer. Our ACS asks directly current customer’s ADFS.
It works like this:

- Our ASP.NET application asks our ACS for authentication
- Our ACS is configured to ask current customer ADFS
- Customer shows ADFS login page
- Authenticated

Our new customer has SAMPL IDP. Options we have for this new customer

A.

The same approach like with current –> do not host ADFS for them and let ACS ask directly our new customer SAML IDP. This however looks not to be possible. We can not configure and see such option in ACS configuration.

Please confirm it is possible or not.

B.

Host AD for our new customer. Configure ADFS and rely to our new customer SAMPL IDP.
In this case we have Active Directory, our ACS connects to it via WsFed and our ADFS then rely all authentications to SAML 2 provider.
I am not sure if this is feasible. Is it?

C.

In Azure AD case we would need to

- host Azure AD for new customer
- "replicate" all users from SAML provider to Azure AD
- change our web application to use Azure AD rather than current ACS

Correct?